# django-haystack SearchView has no as_view()

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, django-haystack

I have a view

```
class CustomSearchView(SearchView):
    template_name = "bunkering/search.html"
    queryset = SearchQuerySet().all()
    form_class = SearchForm
```

subclassing `SearchView` imported with

```
from haystack.forms import ModelSearchForm, SearchForm
from haystack.views import SearchView, FacetedSearchView
```

In my urls.py I use

```
url(r'^search/$', CustomSearchView.as_view(), name='search'),
```

But when I visit my site, I get AttributeError

```
'super' object has no attribute 'as_view'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to also include `from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet`

Comment: Maybe SearchMixin will help https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/blob/master/haystack/generic_views.py#L17

Answer (score 3):

You should import base `SearchView` from `haystack.generic_views` not from `haystack.views`.
Classes from `generic_views` are standard Django class-based views and support `as_view` method.